# How could I pass arguments to invoke AWS lambda function by using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, input, arguments, aws-lambda

In my application,I will input data to invoke my lambda function,how can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not familiar with lambda,but I know that lambda can be triggered by an event,so I want to pass parameter to invoke lambda,can any blue print can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Payload` parameter of the [invoke function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) might be what you are  looking for.

The format is *"bytes or seekable file-like object"* which means a bytes string, or an open filehandle or perhaps a BytesIO?

This works for me:

```
    import boto3
    import json
    import pprint

    params = {"day": "20220410"}
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='my_lambda_function',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(params).encode(),
    )
    pprint.pp(response['Payload'].read())
```

The lambda receives the params in the event dictionary:

```
def my_lambda_function(event, context):
    day = event['day']
```

Answer (score -1):

Since, you have only mentioned

> In my application, I will input data to invoke my lambda

I think you probably want to invoke lambda from you application.

For that,

- Add AWS credentials. [Getting started with Python on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/)
- Import lambda from `boto`.

```
    import boto3    
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
```

- USE `invoke()` to invoke a function with parameters:

```
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='string',
        InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
        LogType='None'|'Tail',
        ClientContext='string',
        Payload=b'bytes'|file,
        Qualifier='string'
    )
```

You can use official documentation to explore more
[Lambda boto Documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)

Also,

Lambda Function can be invoked in following ways:

- AWS services events (example: SNS triggered)
- API created through AWS API Gateway.
- Amazon CloudWatch cron jobs
- API calls leveraging AWS Lambda APIs.

Documentation: [Ways to Invoke AWS Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-dynamodb-create-function.html#with-dbb-invoke-manually)

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. The question specifically asks how to add arguments to a function invocation, you have just pasted the AWS Documentation which merely specifies how to invoke a function.